# Catch Server Side 400 error in NextJS and then delete a cookie

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, next.js

I have a server-side route /auth/refresh to refresh tokens. I send a Post from NextJS client side with the current token and the server searches for it. If it does not find it then it sends a 400 `Error: Refresh token not found`. When this happens I want NextJS to automatically delete the tokens it has client side which will force the user to reauthenticate. The [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#404-page) does not seem to handle this use case. Do you all have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple, when user token is expired you need to set again that cookie with a lifetime of 0/1 ms, then (and here depends a lot how do you handle you unauthorised users) reddirect the user to login/not authorised page. A little code would help to offer you more precise suggestion.